# How to debug avrdude with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, avrdude

I was able to compile `avrdude` on my mac using `bootstrap` and `autotools`. I'd like to see how it's working under debug in Xcode. Any chance to do it? How can i create Xcode project for it? Any converters from autotools makefiles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using this [article](http://blog.burhum.com/post/35555678746/debugging-makefile-based-projects-using-xcode).

In brief:

1. create osx command-line project
2. configure target and scheme to build using external build system - make
3. add sources to the project (and target)
4. set debug breakpoints
5. debug

voila!